# Proving a language is in RE/R/coRE

Tags: turing-machines

Lets say we have a function for a Turing Machine like this one:

```
() = { 1, for any  where () halts only if w is a palindrome of even length
          0, otherwise
```

How can one prove that it belongs (or not) to RE, R, coRE.

I mean, I know we can use a turing reduction using the f-halt to prove that it is not belonging to R. But what about RE/coRE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language is RE if we can halt-accept for any string in the language. A language is coRE if we can halt-reject for any string not in the language. R is the intersection of RE and coRE; a language is R if we can halt-accept on strings in the language and halt-reject on strings not in the language.

You already know that the language isn't R. This can also be seen by Rice's theorem: halting only on palindromes of even length is a semantic property of the accepted language (subset of EPAL), so the inclusion problem isn't decidable. This tells you that the language cannot be both RE and coRE, though it might be neither.

Given a machine M, can we determine that it does only accept strings which are even-length palindromes? This seems unlikely. We would need a way to be sure that all strings - maybe infinitely many - are even-length palindromes. We can't just find a counterexample and be done.

Given a machine M, can we determine that it doesn't only accept strings which are even-length palindromes? We sure can! We can interleave executions of copies of this machine such that arbitrarily many possible input strings get arbitrarily much computing time; if M accepts any particular string, we can eventually find out, and if it accepts one that isn't an even-length palindrome, we can eventually tell.

So, this language:

- is coRE
- is not RE
- is not R

Comment: Ok, so we know that the machine will halt for even length palindromes. But I can't figure out what "only accept strings which are even-length palindromes" means. I mean, we have a machine that can get any input, right? And if it receives an even-length palindrome, it halts, otherwise it loops or something. So what does it mean that we have to determine it accepts only palindromes or not? Doesn't it accept anything and then decide if it's good or not?

Comment: @DragosIancu I take "accept" to mean "halts execution by entering halt_accept". In another sense, a TM must "accept" anything it gets on the tape in that it can't argue or fight back, but that's not what I imagine is usually understood.

Comment: how about if we have a language that is defined like this { 1, it halts for at least one w; 0, otherwise }. Can we say the same thing? that we know we can use a TM that will halt for w and loop otherwise and the language is RE and not coRE?

Comment: @DragosIancu Yes, the conclusion is correct. We can recognize TMs that accept at least one string by trying them on arbitrarily many inputs. If the TMs accept anything, we will eventually find a string they do accept, so we can answer "yes" instances; it must be RE. By Rice's theorem, being non-empty is a semantic property of accepted languages and therefore the language cannot be R. Logically, then, it cannot be coRE.

Comment: So is it ok to assume that if the language is defined like this { 1, for an infinity of words/inputs with some property; 0, otherwise } the language is in coRE (knowing it's not in R) and if a language is defined as { 1, for a finite input of words, 0 otherwise } then it's RE?

Comment: @DragosIancu I'm not completely sure I understand, but I think you're probably getting the right idea: if a language condition is "there exists", then it's RE because you can try all the inputs and halt-accept if you find one that works; if a language condition is "for all", then it's coRE because you can try all the inputs and halt-reject if you find one that doesn't work. Therefore, R languages are those which have equivalent and irreducible conditions of both forms: "there exists" and "for all".

Comment: Yup, exactly my conclusion. I guess I couldn't find a good way to express myself. Thank you again Patrick for the help you've given.